# Node.js: Directory has no method 'basename' when path.basename is used

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of files, and I am trying to get just the `basename` of the files, without their long extensions. Here is an example of what the array looks like:

```
[ 
  '/public/uploads/contentitems/.DS_Store',
  '/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0.png',
  '/public/uploads/contentitems/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1.png',
  '/public/uploads/contentitems/2A431412-A776-4D11-841A-B640DF37C9E2/2A431412-A776-4D11-841A-B640DF37C9E2_2.png' 
]
```

I want to get:

```
[ 
  '.DS_Store',
  '063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0.png',
  '063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0/063012A5-60BC-4A4C-AEC2-56B0D5D99EF0_1.png',
  '2A431412-A776-4D11-841A-B640DF37C9E2/2A431412-A776-4D11-841A-B640DF37C9E2_2.png' 
]
```

According to the docs, the `path.basename` function should return me the file without the path.

But what I get is the following error:

```
TypeError: Object /public/uploads/contentitems has no method 'basename'
```

Here is the code I am using right now:

```
    var walk = function(dir, done) {
        var results = [];
        fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            var pending = list.length;
            if (!pending) return done(null, results);
            list.forEach(function(file) {
                file = dir + '/' + file;
                fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
                    if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                        walk(file, function(err, res) {
                            results = results.concat(res);
                            if (!--pending) done(null, results);
                        });
                    } else {
                        var suffix = getSuffix(file);
                        if (!verObj[suffix]) results.push(file);
                        if (!--pending) done(null, results);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    };

    walk(path, function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        results.forEach(function(file) {
            console.log(path.basename(file));
        });
        self.respond({files: results}, {format: 'json'});
    });
```

I am using `path = require('path');` at the top of my file as well.

Comment: You're sure it's not the first `.DS_Store` that is causing the issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a variable name conflict with `path`.

Use some something else other than `path` to represent the directory you want to walk.

```
walk(path, function(err, results) {
```

You are passing a string named `path` into `walk()`.

```
console.log(path.basename(file));  // <-- path is a string here
```

Comment: Head, meet desk. Still helping people 6 years later ha!